# How to get radio button data tag of dynamically added element

Tags: jquery

I have a group of radio buttons that gets dynamically added to a page.  The code is different radio buttons like this:

```
<div class="option col-6 radioLabelContainer">
        <input type="radio" name="qty-price" id="cost1000" value="333" data-qty="1000" data-each="0.33">
        <label class="radioLabel qtyPrice" for="cost1000" aria-label="cost1000">
          <span></span>
          1000 / $333
          <p style="color: red; display: block;">0.33 each </p>
        </label>
      </div>
```

I get the clicked radio button in jquery like so:

```
$( "#include-price-selection" ).on('click', $("input[name='qty-price']"), function(e) {

});
```

The click above works.  I then try to get the data attribute "qty" like so:

```
$( "#include-price-selection" ).on('click', $("input[name='qty-price']"), function(e) {
  console.log($(this).data("qty"));
});
```

The above logs undefined.

I also try this:

```
 console.log($(e.currentTarget).data("qty"));
```

Also logs undefined.

My assumption is that this or e.currentTarget isn't referencing the actual input but the main eleemnt #include-price-selection?  Maybe I'm wrong on that.  How could I get the desired data attribute?

Comment: `e.target.dataset.qty`. jQuery is really just making things more complex and difficult because you have to learn a second API that kind of mixes with the essential one, for no real benefit any more. I strongly advise to get rid of any jQuery in your projects as fast as you can.